# Count using a category and Median using a category

Tags: excel, vba

I have two problems here.
The data is as follows:

```
Col X Col Y
    A 10
    A 12
    A 
    A 32
    B 11
    B 31
    B 9
    C 8
    C 7
    C 3
    D 1
    D 3
    D 
    D 9
```

I need to do the following:

1. Count the entries in Column Y using the Categories in Column X, for ex. A repeats 4 times in Column X but has 3 total corresponding numbers in column Y, i need the 3 count of the numbers in Column Y.
2. Calculate the median of those numbers using the category (excluding blanks whenever there are, not to be assumed as 0 by the code), for ex. Median for A is 12, Median for D will be 3.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post where you've got to so far? You're most likely to get help where people can see you've tried, it's not just a homework service :)

Comment: Sir, I tried different ways, but nothing would work, had the Column Y data been similar, I'd have used COUNTIFS but this is a new problem i have never worked on. I only post here when I am exhausted of all options.
I very well know this is not a homework service, but yes if someone would help me, I would train atleast 20 more people at my organization of the same. Thanks

Comment: OK, but COUNTIFS works for not null values e.g. `=COUNTIFS(X:X,"A",Y:Y,"<>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 1 is:
`=COUNTIFS(X:X,"A",Y:Y,"<>")`

2 is:
`=MEDIAN(IF(X:X="A",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Y:Y)),Y:Y)))`
*Hold down **ctrl** + **shift** when you're using 2 as it's an array formula*

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you please also explain what the "<>" does in the first one? Like what does it mean?

Comment: All that means is "not blank". So count the number of rows where X="A" and Y is not blank.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much! Learnt something new today.